# Can we read files from server path using any fs method in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

In my case I need to read file/icon.png from cloud storage/bucket which is a token base URL/path. Token resides in header of request.

I tried to use fs.readFile('serverpath') but it gave back error as 'ENOENT' i.e. 'No such file or directory' is existed, but file is existed on that path. So are these methods are eligible to make calls and read files from server or they work only with static path, if that is so then in my case how to read file from cloud bucket/server.

Here i need to pass that file-path to UI, to show this icon.

Answer (score 2):

Use this lib to handle GCS operations.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage

If you do need use `fs`, install https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse, mount bucket to your local filesystem, then use `fs` as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complement Cloud Ace's answer by saying that if you have Storage Object Admin permission you can make the URL of the image public and use it like any other [public URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#storage-make-object-public-nodejs).

If you don't want to make the URL public you can get temporary access to the file by creating a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers).

Otherwise, you'll have to [download the file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs) using the [GCS Node.js Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage).

I posted this as an answer as it is quite long to be a comment.